# If $ b \in K $ is algebraic of degree n over $F$ then $ [F (b):F ]=n $. Is the converse true?

Tags: field-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $K$ be an extension of $F$ if  $ b\in K $ is algebraic of degree $n$  over $F$ then $ [F (b):F]=n $  .

I want to know  if  I  am  given that  $ [F (b):F] =n $ then can I tell that  b  is  algebraic  of  degree  n  over  F?

If  not   can someone  give  me  an example  please?

Thank you in advance.

Edit : I  have  started studying "extension fields" and I have  so many  doubts  , the above question was one of my doubts  .

I have this doubt because there is a theorem in my textbook that  " The element $ a\in K $  is algebraic over F if and only if F (a) is a finite extension over F"

and the next theorem was " If  $ a\in K $  is algebraic of degree n over F, then [F (a):F]=n"

I didn't understand why Mr. Herstein didn't  use " if and only if " term in the second case  .

In my opinion the "if" part is also true but I thought I should ask the experts.

Comment: I understand what you said ? but I did not understand what is the relation with my question ? well I just started to study field theory so please elaborate a little more?

Comment: OK I understood what you said in your statement  but why the converse is not true ?  I think I should edit my question.Why my argument is wrong?

Comment: I didn't understand yet why the converse is not true? can you give me an example.? Sorry for disturbing

Comment: In your example  $ [\mathbb {Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb {Q}] $ = 2 and $ \sqrt {2} $ is algebraic of degree 2 over $ \mathbb {Q} $ so how this example contradicts the converse?

Comment: yes but I didn't ask for that. ...and you stated in your comment  "the converse is not exactly true ". so I am asking for a counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In this case $b^n = p(b)$ where $p$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$, so $b$ is a root of the degree $n$ polynomial $x^n - p(x)$. If $b$ were a root of a lower degree polynomial, then the elements $1,b,\dotsc,b^{n-1}$ would not be linearly independent, so the extension would not be degree $n$.

It's been a while since I studied field theory, so I'm not sure whether the assertion that $1,b,\dotsc,b^{n-1}$ form a basis needs more justification.